# How to Add Watermark to PDF in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, watermark

I need to add watermark to a PDF file using PHP without executing external commands like GhostScript.

It must work with PDF 1.7 containing dynamic content (links, forms) so FPDI doesn't work even with its paid version due to the limitations described here https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/limitations/ (4.3).

The content is confidential and mustn't be sent to any external API so the watermarking PHP code must be purely on my server.

Any advice?

Comment: What else have you researched / tried already? There are various PDF libraries available for PHP, for example. Your question is a bit broad at the moment. It's also bordering on asking for recommendations I think, which is off-topic here.

Comment: P.S. As you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) 
I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: You might also want to look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)